# Are JSF (Java Server Faces) pages sandboxed?

Tags: security, jsf

We let our users upload html to our servers. We need a template language so users can insert variables into the rendered output, iterate over lists, etc.. We're currently using JSF as our template language.

If we let users upload xhtml with JSF tags in it, is there anything bad they can do? Or are they sandboxed?

We deliberately avoided JSP because we don't want a user to insert malicious java code in a page that could run on the server.

Comment: No, it definitely isn't sandboxed. How would you otherwise run your own JSF code in all freedom?

Comment: By "your own JSF code", I thought all you could call was your own tags in a tag library that had been made available to the app? Is it possible to run other code? (We're not letting users upload their own libraries.)

Answer (score 1):

JSF pages are *not* sandboxed, in a security sense.  There are scope limitations, but this is not really the same thing (some overlap, but they have different objectives).  You should probably not allow the upload of JSF code, but you probably will anyway so screen/sanitize the input as best as possible.  Use a whitelist of safe operations if possible.  Blacklists are almost always trivial to escape because an enumeration of possible evil values is impossible.  Be careful, and get your site professionally penetration tested when you're done to make sure you didn't miss anything obvious.

Comment: Can you give an example of an operation that would be bad? Can you give me some pointers on how to implement a whitelist?

Comment: Sorry I'm in a hurry, and off the top of my head I can't think of specific examples, however generally speaking your users may be able to create a view into a model that you don't want them to access (like the database of users, for example).  As for the whitelist the best thing to do is to think of everything possible that your users might use, and put it down as long as it isn't dangerous.  During alpha and beta testing, modify this list as your users encounter issues.  There are other techniques to make this less tedious and manual, but overall a whitelist is a labor intensive activity.

Comment: I guess my question is more basic. How do I implement a whitelist? We don't use beans in our app, just tags.

Comment: If it were me, I would have the whitelist in a file on the server that gets read at startup time, and maybe every 30 minutes or so if it's changed, and during low traffic periods.  Load the whitelist into memory as a HashMap and query it with each tag.  If the tag is present then you're golden.  The HashMap will give you near constant time lookups.  Note that this may not be very scalable, so if scalability is a concern you may need something else.  Watch out for injectable javascript etc. that can be used for XSS attacks.